# jQuery text changing only after second click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm new to javascript and jQuery, and I'm having trouble finding what's wrong with my code. I've written a very simple script that's supposed to change the text of a span on click, but I have to do two clicks to make it work. I have a slider, and the slider works perfectly on click, so I know that it's working on the first click, yet the text takes two clicks to change, and the two events are supposed to happen together. This is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".slider").click(function() {

    $(".btn").toggleClass("movement");

    var newPrice1 = "59.99";
    if ($(".price1-span").text() == "19.99") {
      $(".price1-span").text(newPrice1)
    } else {
      $(".price1-span").text("19.99");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* GENERAL */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  background-image: url(/bbbackground.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

hr {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}


/* H1 */

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 4vh auto 30px auto;
  color: #0B3142;
}


/* DECISION */

.decision {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: #0B3142;
}


/* SLIDER & SLIDER BTN */

.slider {
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: auto 20px;
  background-color: #0F5257;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0.8);
}

.movement {
  left: 20px;
}


/* PLAN CONTAINER */

#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#container div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/* BASIC, PROFESSIONAL, DIAMOND */

.basic {
  padding: 50px 40px;
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238, 80%);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  transition: .5s;
}

.basic:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  background-color: #114b66;
  color: white;
}

.basic:hover h3 {
  color: white;
}

.basic:hover button {
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px black;
}


/* BASIC H3 */

.basic h3 {
  color: #114b66;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.basic h2 {
  font-size: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}


/* SPAN DOLLAR SIGN */

.price {
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 20px !important;
}

.price1-span {
  font-size: 45px !important;
}


/* LEARN MORE BUTTON */

button {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #1d8e96;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgb(151, 151, 151);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title> Pricing Component </title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <h1> Limited Time Offer! </h1>
  <div class="decision">
    <p> Monthly </p>
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="btn"></div>
    </div>
    <p> Anually </p>
  </div>

  <div id="container">
    <div class="basic">
      <h3> Master Plan </h3>
      <h2 class="price"> $ <span class="price1-span"> 19.99 </span></h2>
      <hr>
      <p> 1 TB Storage </p>
      <hr>
      <p> 5 Sites Allowed </p>
      <hr>
      <p> Free email account </p>
      <hr>
      <p> Full Account Access </p>
      <hr>
      <button> learn more </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I highly recommend staying away from jQuery for as long as you consider yourself a beginner. Stick with native Javascript instead; once you've learned that (and if you're any serious about developing there's no way around that anyway), you don't need jQuery at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Cause

The reason is that initially your price elements `text()` is `" 19.99 "`, not `"19.99"`.

```
" 19.99 " == "19.99" // returns false
```

### What's going on?

So when your click handler arrives here on your first click, it goes into your `else` branch, setting it to `"19.99"`. Since doesn't change anything visually, you get the impression that "nothing happens on first click".

2nd click it does find `"19.99"`, thus your comparison returns `true`, so this time your if-branch is executed.

### Simplest way to fix it

To fix the issue, simply remove the leading and trailing space character from your

```
<span class="price1-span"> 19.99 </span>
```

so you end up with

```
<span class="price1-span">19.99</span>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".slider").click(function() {

    $(".btn").toggleClass("movement");

    var newPrice1 = "59.99";
    if ($(".price1-span").text() == "19.99") {
      $(".price1-span").text(newPrice1)
    } else {
      $(".price1-span").text("19.99");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* GENERAL */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  background-image: url(/bbbackground.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

hr {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}


/* H1 */

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 4vh auto 30px auto;
  color: #0B3142;
}


/* DECISION */

.decision {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: #0B3142;
}


/* SLIDER & SLIDER BTN */

.slider {
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: auto 20px;
  background-color: #0F5257;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0.8);
}

.movement {
  left: 20px;
}


/* PLAN CONTAINER */

#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#container div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/* BASIC, PROFESSIONAL, DIAMOND */

.basic {
  padding: 50px 40px;
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238, 80%);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  transition: .5s;
}

.basic:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  background-color: #114b66;
  color: white;
}

.basic:hover h3 {
  color: white;
}

.basic:hover button {
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px black;
}


/* BASIC H3 */

.basic h3 {
  color: #114b66;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.basic h2 {
  font-size: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}


/* SPAN DOLLAR SIGN */

.price {
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 20px !important;
}

.price1-span {
  font-size: 45px !important;
}


/* LEARN MORE BUTTON */

button {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #1d8e96;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgb(151, 151, 151);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<h1> Limited Time Offer! </h1>
<div class="decision">
  <p> Monthly </p>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="btn"></div>
  </div>
  <p> Anually </p>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div class="basic">
    <h3> Master Plan </h3>
    <h2 class="price"> $ <span class="price1-span">19.99</span></h2>
    <hr>
    <p> 1 TB Storage </p>
    <hr>
    <p> 5 Sites Allowed </p>
    <hr>
    <p> Free email account </p>
    <hr>
    <p> Full Account Access </p>
    <hr>
    <button> learn more </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The initial text of the span has spaces around the price, but you don't have that in the string you're comparing with.

You can use `.trim()` to remove surrounding whitespace.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".slider").click(function() {

    $(".btn").toggleClass("movement");

    var newPrice1 = "59.99";
    if ($(".price1-span").text().trim() == "19.99") {
      $(".price1-span").text(newPrice1)
    } else {
      $(".price1-span").text("19.99");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* GENERAL */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  background-image: url(/bbbackground.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

hr {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}


/* H1 */

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 4vh auto 30px auto;
  color: #0B3142;
}


/* DECISION */

.decision {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: #0B3142;
}


/* SLIDER & SLIDER BTN */

.slider {
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: auto 20px;
  background-color: #0F5257;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0.8);
}

.movement {
  left: 20px;
}


/* PLAN CONTAINER */

#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#container div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/* BASIC, PROFESSIONAL, DIAMOND */

.basic {
  padding: 50px 40px;
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238, 80%);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  transition: .5s;
}

.basic:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  background-color: #114b66;
  color: white;
}

.basic:hover h3 {
  color: white;
}

.basic:hover button {
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px black;
}


/* BASIC H3 */

.basic h3 {
  color: #114b66;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.basic h2 {
  font-size: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}


/* SPAN DOLLAR SIGN */

.price {
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 20px !important;
}

.price1-span {
  font-size: 45px !important;
}


/* LEARN MORE BUTTON */

button {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #1d8e96;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgb(151, 151, 151);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title> Pricing Component </title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <h1> Limited Time Offer! </h1>
  <div class="decision">
    <p> Monthly </p>
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="btn"></div>
    </div>
    <p> Anually </p>
  </div>

  <div id="container">
    <div class="basic">
      <h3> Master Plan </h3>
      <h2 class="price"> $ <span class="price1-span"> 19.99 </span></h2>
      <hr>
      <p> 1 TB Storage </p>
      <hr>
      <p> 5 Sites Allowed </p>
      <hr>
      <p> Free email account </p>
      <hr>
      <p> Full Account Access </p>
      <hr>
      <button> learn more </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```